# CoreGraphics error with g++-8 on OS X 10.13

Tags: c++, macos, g++, core-graphics

I'm compiling a program, using g++ 8.1 (from Homebrew) on OS X 10.13.5, that includes some headers from the CoreGraphics framework.  I'm getting some syntax errors from the headers themselves:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGPath.h:391:15: error: expected unqualified-id before '^' token
 typedef void (^CGPathApplyBlock)(const CGPathElement * element);
               ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGPath.h:391:15: error: expected ')' before '^' token
 typedef void (^CGPathApplyBlock)(const CGPathElement * element);
              ~^
               )
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGPath.h:393:53: error: 'CGPathApplyBlock' has not been declared
 CG_EXTERN void CGPathApplyWithBlock(CGPathRef path, CGPathApplyBlock CF_NOESCAPE block)
```

Some googling suggests the caret is some kind of managed pointer(?) but it's unclear whether that is supported in OS X, g++, or clang (the only references I saw to that kind of syntax seem to be for MSVC).

Any ideas on what's going on here, and how to fix or circumvent this error (ideally while still using g++)?  One thought I had was to disable write protection for /System and modify those headers to use * not ^, but unsure if that would just harm more than help.

Comment: That's [block syntax](http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com), not managed pointer syntax. I don't know whether g++ 8.1 supports it or not, though as I've not used g++ in a while. Modifying the headers will likely cause a crash when running the app as blocks and pointers are not the same thing.

Comment: Ah interesting, thanks for the info.  Seems block syntax is not supported by gcc except in Apple's patched, old gcc version.  Is there a way to express block syntax, such as that typedef, using standard C/C++? (without reinventing the wheel)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know. The internal mechanisms of blocks are non-obvious to me.